# What does the phrase "Does the Pope sh** in the woods?" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I heard this phrase in the GTA San Andreas game. Sounds pretty offensive, nonetheless I don't really get what he meant to say.
The context was something like:

- "Hey do you wanna make some money?"
- "Does the Pope shit in the woods?"

[Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4osks2WIJs) the video with CJ saying this phrase.

Comment: Are bears Catholic?

Comment: +1, I love GTA:SA. Could you please tell us where exactly was the phrase? I finished the game many times and I don't remember this at all, rofl.

Comment: It is a shame that an expression with such potential has such a mundane meaning. I would otherwise have taken it to mean that there was a remote possibility of the questioner's hoped-for answer being correct, but the likelihood was small.

Comment: i edited to include a link to the video

Comment: Do popes shit bears? Are the woods catholic?

Comment: If the Pope sh** in the woods, then would Chuck Norris hear it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is a mixture of two sayings meaning the same thing, mixed together for comedy value:

[Is the Pope Catholic?](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/203600.html)

[Do bears sh*t in the woods?](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=do%20bears%20shit%20in%20the%20woods?)

Obviously, the point is that the answer to both questions is obviously "yes".

UPDATED- As Tim correctly points out, the deliberate irony is that the actual answer to this question is presumably "no" ([although he does have a wood nearby...](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=vatican%20city&sll=41.90298,12.449956&sspn=0.012457,0.027874&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Vatican%20City,%20Holy%20See&ll=41.903547,12.453679&spn=0.006228,0.013937&t=h&z=17)).

Comment: In the UK we have another saying in the Same vein "Does [Judith Chalmers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judith_Chalmers) own a passport?" Of course being the host of a travel program then answer again must be yes. My friends and I took the mash-up one step further to say: "Does Judith Chalmers Sh** on the Pope"

Comment: But the Pope obviously does not shit in the woods.

Comment: @Tim - Oh? Do you know the Pope personally?

Comment: @Tim, That's what you'd think. It's also a possible mixture on "Does the Pope wear a silly hat?"

Comment: @Matt: You in the UK might have that saying. I in the UK have never heard it, and apart from context would probably not understand it.

Comment: My personal favorite is "If a bear shits in the woods, and no one is there to hear it, does it make a sound?"

Comment: @Colin - It was a tongue in cheek comment :-). [Reference](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/holidaytypeshub/article-590640/Wish-I-there.html)

Comment: @Tim that's what makes it funny.

Comment: @Amanda: Of course, but it makes the phrase hard to interpret if you haven't heard the others before.

Comment: @Tim, that is also what makes it funny.

Comment: I just want to point out that there is a wood very close to Vatican city, should the Pope require it. http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=vatican+city&sll=41.90298,12.449956&sspn=0.012457,0.027874&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Vatican+City,+Holy+See&ll=41.903547,12.453679&spn=0.006228,0.013937&t=h&z=17

Comment: "*Where the pope does his business* is *his business*" -GTA

Answer (score 14):

It's a mash-up of two very popular phrases: "Is the pope Catholic?" (well, of course he is!) and "does a bear shit in the woods?" (where else would he do it?)

It's a humorous but **very** rude way to say "Of course - why would you even ask?"

Answer (score 3):

Urban [dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Does%20the%20Pope%20shit%20in%20the%20woods?) has a sensible explanation:

> This is a sarcastic answer to a question with an obvious answer of "yes." Taken as a combination of the similarly-intended ones, "Does a bear shit in the woods?" and "Is the Pope Catholic?"