# What is the origin of the term “sure as <SHEXPLETIVE>”?

Tags: etymology

Where did the term "sure as shit" originate?  I have googled and googled, and I cannot find a source.

Comment: Keep Googling.  I'm sure the monks carefully documented it when Brother Ambrose first said it.

Comment: Read the book "Everybody Poops"

Comment: it is an expression from the 50's, according to Google Books: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sure+as+shit&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csure%20as%20shit%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *Shit*  has been used  metaphorically in a many expressions which have become popular in recent decades:  *meaning "misfortune, trouble" is attested from 1937. Shit-faced "drunk" is 1960s student slang; shit list is from 1942. Up shit creek "in trouble" is from 1937 (compare salt river). To not give a shit "not care" is from 1922. Pessimistic expression Same shit different day attested by 1989. Shitticism is Robert Frost's word for scatological writing.* http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=shit

Comment: I feel thoroughly educated now, @Josh61!  Let's not forget "shitload" or a favorite phrase, "he knows shitloads of shit!". http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shitload

Comment: @Skooba: I'm reliably informed that Queen Elizabeth never farts or poops, and apparently although the Pope does poop occasionally, he [only does it in the woods](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28897/what-does-the-phrase-does-the-pope-sh-in-the-woods-mean) (that's a little-known fact unearthed by our sleuths here on ELU! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, but the question remains, why has 'shit' become 'sure' only from the 50's?

Comment: @FumbleFingers being an American I forgot about the Queen!! Also, if the pope is in the woods are bears wearing funny hats?

Comment: To the OP are we asking "What" the phrase means or "When" it became popular?

Comment: @Josh61: The only written instance I can find before 1950 is actually a misdated later translation of a German original text. The first two *genuine* instances in Google Books are [one in 1959, and one in 1960](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sure+as+shit%22&biw=1117&bih=861&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1950%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1960&tbm=bks). The usage didn't really "take off" until at least the 80s.

Comment: [Cassell's Dictionary of Slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=5GpLcC4a5fAC&pg=PA1392&dq=%22sure+as+shit%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisvLq82tHJAhWFXD4KHaN0AdUQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22sure%20as%20shit%22&f=false) has an entry for it (two down from 'sure as hell') with some dates and “logic” (…rolls downhill …).

Comment: Traditionally, among children of a certain age, all such phrases are reputed to have come from Uranus.

Answer (score 1):

The emphatic "sure as *hell*" is in use in the late 19th century and possibly earlier. I did only a [quick check](https://books.google.com/books?id=-RoLAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA228&dq=%22sure%20as%20hell%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNkND4vNHJAhUB7SYKHfobALgQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=%22sure%20as%20hell%22&f=false).

[image: The Southwestern Reporter: National Reporter System, Volume 46, Volume 46]

The Southwestern Reporter: National Reporter System, Volume 46 (1898).

"Sure as shit" would be an analogous formation, which seems to have risen in popularity post World War II.

P.S. See also "sure as *heck*" which arises in texts the 1930s   and "sure as *shootin'*" which is from the 1840s.  These phrases are all very probably in use considerably earlier than their attestations in written texts.

Comment: That's not to mention 4350 written instances of [*sure as **fuck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sure+as+fuck%22). Okay, there are four times as many instances of *sure as **shit***, but I think that might be misleading. Even if the coarser version were actually *more* common in real-world speech, it seems quite possible to me that many writers/editors might simply "tone it down" before going into print.

Comment: I don't think an answer of "this means that" with one word changed is helpful. Especially since sure as hell and sure as shit mean the same thing.